# WPF Setting ColumnDefinition.Width in Style doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to change the `Width` of a `ColumnDefinition` from `"Auto"` to `"*"` using a `Style` applied to my `ColumnDefinition`. In my `Style` is a `DataTrigger` bound to the `IsChecked` property of a `CheckBox` called `CheckMe`.

**Sample code:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto">
            <ColumnDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckMe,Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="*" />
                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="300" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=CheckMe,Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ColumnDefinition.Style>
        </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Green">
        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckMe" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock Text="Use * width" />
        </CheckBox>
    </Border>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Second column" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In my sample code I'm also setting the `MinWidth` property, which **does** work.

It this possible to do? Maybe using a custom `AttachedProperty` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing the explicit width declaration

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto">
```

And set it in the style

```
<ColumnDefinition>
     <ColumnDefinition.Style>
         <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
             <Setter Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" Value="Auto"/>
```

---

> If you want to switch some property value with triggers based on some
>   condition, you need to set those properties' default value in the
>   style itself otherwise no matter what values you set in your setter
>   the properties' value will always be overridden by the local values of
>   those properties due to [dependency property value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

Comment: It appears to work, is this behavior documented somewhere or is it just common XAML/WPF knowledge?

Comment: Yeah, this is usefull. Vote just now. Solved my issue.